# Give a tip window when mouse is over a particular text

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-addins

I am developing an addin to Visual Studio editor. Does anyone know how to provide a tip window in editor?

MSDN lacks enough description as to how the `IVsTipWindow` interface is used. Please help me out.

Comment: You have to implement this Interface and then write your own implementation for the `Paint()` methods as its upto your plugin to decide how the tooltip should work. You can find more here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee197646.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wish to show the user a small window of what to enter without using a message box. If so why not use a tooltip?

```
ToolTip toolTip1;
```

Next make a hover event for your control and place this in the method

```
toolTip1.SetToolTip(sender as Control, "Some text in balloon!");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx